# addEventListener() not working on small screens

Tags: javascript, wordpress, addeventlistener

I've got a table on my wordpress, with a button on each row, which creates a small form when you click on it ([on this page](http://tours.fhuszti.com/activites-du-mois/)).
It's working perfectly fine, except when you change your browser's width to <768px, then nothing happens.

This is my main call :

```
var buttons = [];
if (jQuery(window).width() > 768)
    buttons = document.querySelectorAll('td button');
else
    buttons = document.querySelectorAll('div button');

/*
 Add a click event to all buttons inside the table
 */
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', clickCheck);
}
```

On small screens, the table elements become divs, so I had to define the `buttons` array differently.
Now this is the `clickCheck()` function :

```
function clickCheck(e) {
    console.log('ok');
    // if first click on the button
    if (e.target.textContent === 'Inscription') {
        // Cleaning an eventual earlier click on another button
        for (var j = 0; j < buttons.length; j++) {
            if (buttons[j].textContent === 'Fermer') {
                buttons[j].parentNode.removeChild(buttons[j].parentNode.firstChild);
                buttons[j].textContent = 'Inscription';
            }
        }

        // Popping the form
        formPop(e);
        e.target.textContent = 'Fermer';
    }
    // if form submission
    else {
        // Depopping the form
        formDepop(e);
        e.target.textContent = 'Inscription';
    }
}
```

On screens smaller than 768px, the 'ok' isn't appearing in the console, so the event isn't read. I've checked and my `buttons` array is fine even on small screens, so the problem has to come from `addEventListener()`.

Any clue ? :)

Comment: I doubt we will be able to see what's going on without seeing your HTML and being able to play with the window width ourselves.  Probably you have a layout or selector problem both of which require seeing the HTML to understand.

Comment: You can follow the link in my post, you'll get to the page with the table, and you'll be able to see the HTML and play with the window width :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of code running in your page so I don't know the root case, but here's the general problem.

When you do this at startup:

```
 buttons = document.querySelectorAll('div button');
```

You are getting a different array of button elements than what ends up visible in your page.  You can physically compare the original `buttons` array with what happens when you run a new `document.querySelectorAll('div button')` at the time of the click (I did so in the debugger).  The first will contain 10 buttons, the second will contain 20 buttons.  I think some code in your page is generating dynamic content AFTER you hook up the event handlers and what you're seeing and interacting with in the page is the dynamic content that was created after you ran your code to add click handlers so the visible content has no event handlers on it.

Comment: Alright got it, I figured it was something along those lines but I didn't have the technical explanations.
I put the event handlers in a window load event, and now it seems to be working correctly. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Durden - If these buttons are being created via some sort of ajax driven code, then it may be blind luck if your fix works on the window load event.  It might just be that the ajax calls are currently finishing before window load so it is working, but they are not necessarily guaranteed to be that way with a slower day for the server or a slower connection.  You really should understand how the buttons are created and make absolutely sure you hook up to them after they are created.

Comment: @Durden - If I was code reviewing your fix, I wouldn't accept it until you could explain how you "know" when the buttons are being created and when they are guaranteed to be done being created.  The fact that `window.onload` happens to work right now is not enough.

Comment: Well no, I only use Ajax to process the form after submission, those buttons are created directly in the HTML file. So they should be already created every time the window is finished loading, right ? Also, I have no idea how I could go about making sure my buttons are created before I hook them up, do you have any leads ?

Comment: @Durden - If the 20 buttons exist in your HTML and are not created via Javascript, then you are fine.  I was under the impression that the second 10 are created by some Javascript.  If that's the case, you have to understand how that Javascript works and what events it has you can plug into to know when it is done.

Comment: Oh you're right, only 10 buttons exist in my HTML, I don't know where those 10 others come from. I'll look into that, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Your first code is only being run once, right? I bet it works on small screens if you load the page small, but not if you load it wider than 768 and then resize down to small.

Basically what appears to be happening is that the event listeners are being added when the page is greater than 768 wide, but the selection of *what* to add them to is based on exactly that.

Comment: Nop it never works, whether I go to the link from my phone or from my pc.

Comment: Well your code to add listeners is trying to add them to a button inside a table cell at 768 and below: `buttons = document.querySelectorAll('td button');`

Do these elements exist in your html?

Comment: These elements only exist above 768px, that's why I had to define buttons differently for smaller screens (with 'div button', as table cells are replaced by divs on small screens). With my if/else, the event listener should be added to the buttons regardless of the width, right ?

Comment: My guess is that for some reason, the small view is not yet available when your initial code is run. Running this code in the console works as expected `buttons = document.querySelectorAll('div button'); for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {buttons[i].addEventListener('click', clickCheck); }`

Comment: Cheers, that seemed to be the problem !